# Help with Absolute Value Mathematics

Tags: absolute-value

Currently, I am having trouble with the following questions listed below:

1. Solve the equation 
   $$\left\lvert x-2\right\rvert -\left\lvert x+ 3\right\rvert =x^2 - 1$$

   For this question, I have drawn the graph for both, and found that there are two points of intersection and hence two solutions.

   I found that the point $-1$ was a point of intersection, but when I tried subbing it back into the equation, the answers were not equal, leaving me confused. I was unable to find the other answer, although I am aware that it is less than -1(due to graphing it)
2. Consider the equation 
   $$\left\lvert  x^2+3x+2 \right\rvert = 1 $$

   - Find the values for $x$ when $$  x^2+3x+2 >0$$ and those for which $$  x^2+3x+2 <0$$

     For this part, I first factorized $x^2+3x+2$. I got $(x+2)(x+1)$.
     For the greater than zero, I got negative $1$ and for less than I got $-2$.
   - Hence, using the definition of absolute value, solve $\left\lvert x^2+3x+2 \right\rvert=1$.

     I am somewhat confused by this part. I am not sure how to use the definition of a abolute value to solve the above, so I tried using the quadratic formula instead, which gave me the answer: $x=\dfrac{-3+\sqrt{5}}2$ or $x=\dfrac{-3-\sqrt{5}}2$

Thank you for your time

Comment: The statement *"equation is less than zero, or greater than zero"* is never heard of. Equation has already been an equality, how can you compare it with $0$.

Comment: sorry, I didn't type that part up correctly, was trying to edit it.

Comment: OK, now a new problem emerges, is it possible for an absolute-valued expression be less than $0$?

Comment: whoops there aren't supposed to be absolute value signs for that part, will edit. Fixed...sorry.

Comment: You're looking for intervals where $x^2+3x+2>0$ and $x^2+3x+2<0$ not single points,

Comment: For 2(ii) I would just use the quadratic formula to solve $x^2+3x+2=1$ and $x^2+3x+2=-1$ separately.

Comment: I did that, and for the the positive arm I got what I wrote above, and for the negative arm I got no solution since the discriminant was less than 0.

Comment: @ChemistryStudent: Then that's your answer. I don't see how you're supposed to use part (i) usefully there either.

Comment: For part 1, you'd need to reveal _how_ you got the wrong answer $-1$. Without that it is impossible to tell where you're going wrong.

Comment: For part 1, I first sketched the graph y=|x-2| -|x+3|, then i sketched x^2-1. For the first equation, i subbed in when x=0, and I got y=-1. For the second equation, I shifted a normal parabola down one, which also hit -1.

Comment: @ChemistryStudent: Yes, and how did that look? What did you do then?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

In principle any equation with absolute values can be reduced to one or more systems of equations and inequalities.

E.g. , for the equation 1) we have:

note that $x-2\ge 0 \iff x\ge 2$ and $x+3 \ge 0 \iff x\ge -3$ so the equation reduces to the three systems:

$$
\begin{cases}
x<-3\\
2-x+(x+3)=x^2-1
\end{cases}
\lor
\begin{cases}
-3\le x<2\\
2-x-(x+3)=x^2-1
\end{cases}
\lor
\begin{cases}
x\ge 2\\
x-2-(x+3)=x^2-1
\end{cases}
$$

can you solve these? 
Use the same method for equation 2) and find:

$$
\begin{cases}
x<-2\\
x^2+3x+2=1
\end{cases}
\lor
\begin{cases}
-2\le x<1\\
-(x^2+3x+2)=1
\end{cases}
\lor
\begin{cases}
x\ge 1\\
x^2+3x+2=1
\end{cases}
$$
If you well understand  this then you can find some shortcut...

Comment: This is how I generally solve simple equations containing absolute values. +1

Comment: Sketching a graph does help cut down on the work -- it shows that only the middle system has a chance of being solvable (ind if the graph is just slightly precise you can read the solutions diretly off from it).

Answer (score 1):

In part 1, if you did start by sketching the functions, you should get something like this, from which the solutions can be read off directly:

[image: Graph of the two functions]

Comment: thats what my graph looked like, but why is it when i sub in -1 to the equations, I get 1 on the LHS and 0 on the RHS, or am I not supposed to be subbing it in?

Comment: @ChemistryStudent: How would that graph lead you to think that $x=-1$ is a solution? You're looking for the _intersections_ between the two graphs, and at $x=-1$ they certainly don't intersect. At that point the parabola is $0$ but the zig-zag thing is clearly _above_ $0$. Instead you should see an intersection at $x=0$ (which is easily seen to be exact) and one at $x=-2$ (which you may verify by plugging in).

Comment: oh whoops...i misread the graph..I guess I just saw the intersection there and...yeah...thank you. I understand how 0 is an answer now...but not sure about -2, my graph is not accurate enough...

Comment: @ChemistryStudent: Then you just plug $x=-2$ into the equation. You get $4-1$ on both sides.

Comment: If I am drawing info from a graph, do I still show equation method?

Comment: @ChemistryStudent: Depends on what your teacher expects. That is not really a mathematical question -- but a real mathematician would feel fully convinced just by seeing the graph.

Answer (score 0):

To solve $|x-2|-|x+3| = x^2-1$, the standard way is to split $x$ into three cases:

1. $x<-3$
2. $-3 \le x < 2$
3. $2\le x$

Take the first case as example. If $x<-3$, then the absolute signs become
$$\begin{align*}
-(x-2)+(x+3) &= x^2-1\\
6 &= x^2\\
x &= \pm\sqrt6
\end{align*}$$
Then it is necessary to check and reject roots. Since we are considering $x<-3$, there is no real $x$ from the equation in this range.

Then move on the next two cases.

---

Question 2 is similar. To solve $|x^2+3x+2|=1$, consider the cases when the content inside each absolute sign switches sign:

1. $x^2+3x+2 < 0$, i.e. $-2<x<-1$
2. $x^2+3x+2 \ge 0$, i.e. the union of $x\le -2$ and $x\ge -1$.

Solve each case by replacing the absolute sign with parentheses and optionally a negative sign, and remember to check your answer.